# How to I go to next activity

Tags: android

I am new in android how to go next activity in button click.

```
  button.setoncliklistener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onclick (View v){


    }
     });
```

Comment: read the docs first. This is very basic stuff and if you see the samples you should be able to do it yourself

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815224/moving-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526533/moving-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button.setoncliklistener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onclick (View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent ( this, next.class);
    startActivity(intent);  
    finish();   
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have ActivityA and ActivityB and you want to move from ActivityA to ActivityB, then

In ActivityA.class, use:

```
  button.setoncliklistener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onclick (View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent ( getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(intent);  
    finish();   
     }
 });
```

**Tutorials:**

- [Android Hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/)
- [MKYong](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/)

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setoncliklistener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onclick (View v){
          Intent intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
          finish();//If want to finish previous activity, if not then dont write this line.

    }
     });
```