# Call a specific activity of another application. Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-package-managers

I am relatively new to android and currently I am working on a complicated project for which I need to complete a requirement. I am a little stuck here.

This is the in game activity for guest users after trial ends.

```
public class GuestUserActivity extends Activity {
public Button mMenuButton;
public Button mRegisterButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.guest_user_screen);

    mMenuButton = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.Menu);
    mRegisterButton = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.Register);

    mMenuButton.setOnClickListener(m_MenuClicked);
    mRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(m_RegisterClicked);
}

public View.OnClickListener m_MenuClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent ( getBaseContext(), MainMenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
};


public View.OnClickListener m_RegisterClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
      //What to write here?
    }
};
}
```

Corresponding Layout:
[image]

So when the user clicks the register button. I want to launch a specific activity of another application.

Comment: You want to go into register activity after you click a button? If yes, here's it is for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815224/moving-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android.

Comment: the two activities are not part of the same program. As mentioned, my main application launches another application which in my case is a game. So from a game activity mentioned I want to go to the launcher applications register activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                launchIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                ComponentName cp = new ComponentName("Your App Packge Name that Contains Register Activity", "Register Activity Name");
                launchIntent.setComponent(cp);

                startActivity(launchIntent);
```

I hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you properly, you want to start a different app from your app? If that is the case, try:

```
    Intent i;
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    try {
        i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app package name");
        if (i == null)
            throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        startActivity(i);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    }
```

You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

Comment: No, this I have already achieved. I have launched the application. Now I want to exit the launched app back to a previous app's specific activity. Which in my case is a registration page.